# Is digitization process without semiconductors an option? (The need for semiconductors in signal digitization)

Tags: adc

Please excuse this stupid question, I am a complete humanitarian, but for one of my works I need a detailed answer: is it possible to assemble somehow an analog-to-digital converter (ADC) without using semiconductors today? Have lamps performed this particular function before?

Comment: Are vacuum tubes (*valves* to some) allowed in your ADC? Most of our modern ADC methods were first developed before semiconductors were available. For the types of ADC that need a *counter*, you could use a type of counting tube known as **dekatron**, which displays a digital result. And this raises another question: for your digital result, one wonders what human interpretive powers are required? For example, we interpret a thermometer scale to give a digital result.

Comment: Thank you, I knew that vacuum tubes or lamps had been used before, and apparently that's why computers were so huge. If today we create such a scheme for results are not interpreted by a person, but then processed inside the scheme, does this mean that the schemes must be huge? That is, semiconductors have simply made electronics portable, but have not introduced anything significantly new into the possibilities of production and working with a digital signal?

Comment: "Lamps" were never used for what you are talking about.  A lamp lights up if you give it power - that's about it.  Thermionic valves (also called vacuum tubes) were used for a lot of electronic stuff - digital as well as analog - before transistors and integrated circuits were invented.

Comment: The electromechanical relay was invented around the year 1840, so theoretically, it would have been possible to build a fully functional digital computer then. However, the computer would have been extremely large, extremely expensive, extremely power-hungry, and extremely slow. But it's true that semiconductors haven't introduced anything "truly new" to digital computing; they have "merely" made computing devices much smaller, much cheaper, much more efficient, and much faster.

Comment: Remember TURING machine ...

Comment: Why do you want to take humanity back a century?

Comment: Here's one. https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/eb/8e/9f/32ad53d114d2d6/US2272070.pdf

Comment: Thanks to everyone! No, I don't want to "roll back" anything. I'm just asking a question to sort it out. In my native language, "vacuum lamps" means "vacuum tubes". I apologize for the inaccuracy of terminology.

Comment: i can think of a hydraulic version ... vertical pipe that has a row of holes along its length

Comment: @Antonio51 Turing machine is a hypothetical device not a real one.

Comment: Mechanical machine decoding Enigma is a "hypothetical" device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no it's not possible to make an ADC without semiconductors.

To explain...

Your question doesn't give any performance specifications or even technical parameters, so any answer must contain some suppositions.

Here, the definition of an ADC used will be one within the specification range of, let's say, 95% of the ADCs currently sold by volume.

So that's not 95% of the variety of parts on the market but 95% of the quantity sold. The missing 5% is to disregard particularly unusual parts well out of the ordinary.

The characteristics of these parts are covered by the following ranges:

- Precision 8 to 20 bits
- Conversion rate 50 ksps to 100 Msps
- Input voltage (+/- or +) 0.1 to 6 V
- Reliability 100,000 MTBF min.

Electronic circuits without semiconductors falling within these characteristics are impractical or impossible to build.

Valve solutions would have a very low MTBF, probably below 500 hours (21 days) and not meet the precision.

With no bearing on the above, it's my guess that 95% of the ADCs sold by volume in the last 2 years are 8-bit and 12-bit converters within MCUs.

Comment: That's a crucial comment for my cultural research. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

There was [at least one high speed analog to digital converter made by Bell Labs using vacuum tube technology.](https://hackaday.com/2022/06/08/retrotechtacular-the-forgotten-vacuum-tube-a-d-converters-of-1965/)

By the time the team working on it got it to work properly, another team had built a smaller, cheaper, and less power hungry analog to digital converter.

If you are limited to tubes (or valves,) you are probably better off doing as much of your signal processing as possible on the analog signal.

Digital signal processing requires far more transistor equivalents than analog processing.

Take the simplest operation: gain.  All you do is multiply your signal by some fixed amount.

If you stay analog, you can use at most a handful (or maybe just one) transistor equivalent (one vacuum tube.)

If you digitize your signal, you'll need dozens of tubes (or transistors) to hold the digitized value.  You'll need dozens more to do the multiplication.  Once you have it multiplied, you have to store the result somewhere - dozens more transistors or tubes.

---

[Analog computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_computer) was a thing before transistors and integrated made digital signal processing cheap common.

Comment: I worked, in the 70th, on an EAI x000 or more (don't remember exactly, potentiometers were motorized) analog computer ... "Faster" than some PC for some "particular" problems ...  Something as this one first picture https://all-andorra.com/eai-pacer-100-600-computers/

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 3):

Sure. An ADC with adequate performance for telephony (5 bits @ 6kHz) was developed ca. 1937, using a dozen or so vacuum tubes. It was patented first in France, but below image is from the [US Patent 2,272,070](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/eb/8e/9f/32ad53d114d2d6/US2272070.pdf) .  If you wanted to eliminate the crude (probably selenium) rectifiers of the day you'd need a few more tubes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You haven't offered any parameters or bounds, and this is important to do.  A balance scale with a reference weight is a 1 bit ADC telling you whether a mass under test is lighter or heavier than the reference.  I don't know if it meets your criteria.

https://dewesoft.com/daq/history-of-analog-to-digital-converters indicates a 5-bit adc in the '30s, before transistors

Answer (score 0):

The simplest ADC is a comparator, it has one bit output. This is certainly possible to do without semiconductors. If the input variable is force instead of voltage, it is known as a pushbutton, or a scale.

Using a comparator, a clock, and a counter, plus a few extra bits, you can make an [integrating ADC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_ADC). That should be doable without semiconductors, perhaps with display on nixie tubes, although of course it would be rather impractical.

Using a filter, a clock and a comparator, you can make a sigma delta ADC, which outputs a sequence of bits whose average value is the input voltage. Also doable without semiconductors.

The ideal output format would of course be perforated tape.

However the problem would be what to do with the digital value. Once it is digitized, you can display it, print it, or transmit it. If you intend to print it on perforated tape, you could even make a mechanical ADC. All doable, and totally impractical of course.

I guess it was not done back in the day because the oldskool datalogger, a needle writing on a rolling sheet of paper like an EKG or a seismograph, has quite good resolution and produces human-readable results (vs perforated tape) for a relatively low cost...

However if you intend to process the data, you'd need a computer, or at least a microcontroller. And doing that without semiconductors was only ever possible for large organizations with huge budgets, due to the [monstrosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ENIAC#Components) of the thing. Even audiophiles find this too impractical, and that's saying something.